# Best Methods for updating serialized columns in database

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Iam currently unserializing the data retrieved from database then updating the value as per by requirement & then serializing the values & running update query.

Similarly for implementing search on the serialized columns, I have unserialize & compare the values and mine search is like google search. So you can imagine it will be serializing for each requests.

I want to optimize it. Some methods that can improve my current method.

Comment: the ideas suggested by you guys in short was nto to have serailized column but Iam constructing a plugin & I can alter the table structure avaialble rather find optimizing ways

Comment: sry for the mistake:                                                the ideas suggested by you guys in short was nto to have serailized column but Iam constructing a plugin & I cannot alter the table structure avaialble rather find optimizing ways

Comment: If you store a serialized list of data attributes in the database, then they cannot reasonably be used in queries. Such columns can only ever be evaluated by the application. So if it's solely structured runtime meta data, go ahead. But if you want to search within this meta data blob, then you cannot use PHPs serialize format. Make the serialization XML, so you can at least use `ExtractValue()` or text search with some concessions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't used a serialized column of a DB for storing those values, use a proper search engine instead. In my case, I always use [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene), using [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html).

You can build a Lucene Index very easily, just by defining documents and the fields you wish to store of those documents, then searching will be very efficient. If you want some docs, [here](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2008/06/zend-search-lucene-quick-start.html) and [here](http://devzone.zend.com/article/91) you have some tutorials on how to use it, altough the official docs pointer first I find them quite explicative.

Hope I can help!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds really unefficient. Have a look at solr/lucene for a real document search system.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not serialised in your database then you should be able to query specific values without the overhead of having to serialise and unserialise.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for updating serialized columns in database is **not to have serialized columns at all.** Period.

Map your serialized data into related tables and update whatever value using SQL query